# Difference in row count with AND and WHERE clause during a FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about a FULL OUTER JOIN I want to make of 2 tables.

First I have the PMCContract Table with approximately 10000 rows
Then I have the DirPartyTable with approximately 17000 rows

Those tables can be joined together on the key PARTYID that you will find in both tables. When I would outer join those I end up with 23000 rows, since not all rows in the DIRPARTYTABLE have a contract (unique key of PMCContract)

Now the following thing is what makes me confused. Within the PMCCONTRACT table I have a field CONTRACTSTATUS (int) which if it is labelled '5', I want to leave it out entirely. It should not be joined.

The following statement gives me 23000 rows, which seems to be correct

```
SELECT
PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID
,PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS
,DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID

FROM PMCCONTRACT

FULL OUTER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE
ON DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID = PMCCONTRACT.PARTYID
    AND PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS <> 5
```

But when I try a different code, when I decide to only join the '5's, it gives me 27000 rows instead of only 17000 that I would expect (Since there are only 8 contracts with the label '5'). Now I also think the above result cannot be trusted, since using '=' instead of '<>' doesn't show the opposite results.

```
SELECT
PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID
,PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS
,DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID

FROM PMCCONTRACT

FULL OUTER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE
ON DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID = PMCCONTRACT.PARTYID
    AND PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS = 5
```

So then I thought let's use the WHERE clause instead (however, since I join multiple tables, I'm not sure whether I can use this). This gives me around 10000 rows, which is clearly not enough.

```
SELECT
PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID
,PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS
,DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID

FROM PMCCONTRACT

FULL OUTER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE
ON DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID = PMCCONTRACT.PARTYID
    WHERE PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS <> 5
```

Now, when I select '=5' in combination with the WHERE clause, it gives me indeed exactly the 8 I would expect.

```
SELECT
PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID
,PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS
,DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID

FROM PMCCONTRACT

FULL OUTER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE
ON DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID = PMCCONTRACT.PARTYID
    WHERE PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS = 5
```

Conclusion so far for me is that 
- the combination of 'AND and <>' gives me the correct data, it seems
- the combination of 'AND and =' gives me the incorrect data
- the combination of 'WHERE and <>' gives me the incorrect data
- the combination of 'WHERE and =' gives me the correct data

I obviously miss something obvious here, but I hope some of you can enlighten me!

Kind regards,
Ad

Comment: Move the WHERE clause condition to the ON clause, to get true outer join result.

Comment: What is an example of data you expect to see or not see, but isn't what you expect?   Telling us the count of rows doesn't give enough information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: You need to think carefully about what a full outer join means. It's "join the tables based on these conditions *and* include all rows from either table that failed to be joined". This means that if you make the `ON` clause conditions *stricter* (a match is less likely), we expect the row count to go *up*, and if we make the condition laxer (a match is more likely), we expect the row count to go down. Many people find this counter-intuitive. (That with just equalities. Inequalities really screw things up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take into account the fact that PMCCONTRACT and therefore CONTRACTSTATUS does not exist. So replace condition

```
WHERE PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS = 5
```

with

```
WHERE (PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS is null OR PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS = 5)
```

and

```
WHERE PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS <> 5
```

with

```
WHERE (PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS is null OR PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS <> 5)
```

Best regards,
Johan

Answer (score 1):

Filtering conditions with `FULL JOIN`s are just totally confusing.

My recommendation is to filter in a subquery:

```
SELECT c.CONTRACTID, c.CONTRACTSTATUS, dp.PARTYID
FROM (SELECT c.*
      FROM PMCCONTRACT c
      WHERE c.CONTRACTSTATUS <> 5
     ) c FULL OUTER JOIN
     DIRPARTYTABLE dp
     ON dp.PARTYID = c.PARTYID
```